# Chrome doesn't recognise login form

Tags: php, html, forms, google-chrome, authentication

I am currently developing a login form for my website. Whenever I use it with chrome, I am not being asked to save my password. However, it works in other browsers (Tested with Edge, Firefox and Internet Explorer).

**This is my login form:**

```
<div id="login">
    <div id="loginbox">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form action="./login.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="loginform-usrname"><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="loginform-passwd"><br>
            <input style="display: none;" type="text" name="page" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" id="loginform-btn">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The form is submitted as a plain post form (without using any javascript).

Another thing worth mentioning is that the actual login script is running on a different page than the one, where the login form is located. However, in case the user types in the wrong password, the same form is displayed on the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find out the reason for the problem: Right after the login, the php script redirected the user back to the last page.
However, the redirect instantly closed the dialog where the user has to choose whether chrome should remember the password.

I switched from an instant php redirect to a delayed redirect via javascript and it works now.